# Make a trigger for some arguments

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need to create a trigger to perform this argument :
Whenever there is a new input for “numstudent” and “codsub”  in the table exams , if the new grade are superior(need to be the grade for the same “numstudent” and “codsub”)the trigger needs to erase the old grade from table exam and create a new table called “NegativeExams”

Table of students :

| numstudent | name | class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alberto | B |
| 2 | Fran | B |
| 3 | Antonio | A |
| 4 | Rita | C |

table subjects:

| codsub | name | precedencia |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mat1 | mathematics1 | NULL |
| mat2 | mathematics 2 | mat1 |
| prog1 | programation1 | NULL |
| prog2 | programation2 | prog1 |

table Exams :

| id | numstudent | codsub | grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | mat1 | 16 |
| 2 | 1 | mat2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | prog1 | 11 |
| 4 | 1 | prog2 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | prog2 | 19 |
| 6 | 2 | prog1 | 13 |
| 7 | 2 | mat1 | 8 |
| 8 | 2 | mat2 | 6 |

I try this way:

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkgrades after update
    ON exams
    for each row
    AS
    begin
```

First I need to verify if the new grades are superior to the old ones , if this condition is true , the new grade need to be added to the exams table and de old one should be erase from that table but added to a new table “NegativeExams”

```
      IF NEW.nota > OLD.nota THEN
    INSERT INTO exames VALUES (NEW.id,NEW.nota);
    
     ELSE
    INSERT INTO Examesbaixo values (New.id,New.nota)
        END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it may help you out. Add you query in the mentioned area. After that execute the code in the query window. your trigger will be added

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `dbname`.`tablename_AFTER_UPDATE`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `dbname`$$
CREATE TRIGGER `dbname`.`tablename_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `tablename` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
    #write your query here
    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```